# Can we obtain cotriples from certain simplicial objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'll be rather general here, but I do not think the question is imprecise.

It is known that given a cotriple $\bot:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ we can construct a canonical simplicial object of $\mathcal{C}$.  In general, are there qualities of a simplicial object that indicate that it is in fact the one associated to some cotriple? Or more concretely, given a simplicial object, are there properties that it can satisfy so that we can construct a comonad, or is all of the necessary information lost in the construction of such an object?

-------------------------(EDIT)------------------------------

Okay this edit is made months later, because I realized that my question is perhaps not exactly well posed.  What I really want to know, and still haven't made time to actually investigate (because I don't think it'd be hard to play with, from a homological algebra point of view), is an answer to the question: Given a a functor $F:C\to S(C)$ when is it induced by a comonad (where by $S(C)$ I just mean simplicial objects in $C$)?   We have one direction of a correspondence that takes comonads to simplicial functors on a category (perhaps with some restriction of the domain of the functor). Is there a way of going back?

Comment: Can you say precisely how you construct a simplicial object of C from a comonad on C?  What you write isn't literally true: e.g. there is a unique comonad on the empty category C, but we can't construct a simplicial object of C from it, since there are no simplicial objects in C.  Do you mean, for instance, to start with a comonad on C _and an object of C_?  

Comment: It sounds like you have the bar construction in mind, isn't that always acyclic? do you have other canonical examples in mind?

Comment: Right, Sean, presumably he is thinking of some version of the bar construction - but since there are several similar things called the "bar construction", we need to know which. 

Comment: At the root of one such bar construction is the simple observation that the algebraist's $\Delta$ (the category of finite ordinals with monoidal product given by ordinal concatenation) is the initial strict monoidal category with a monoid. Equivalently, $\Delta^{op}$ is the free strict monoidal category with a comonoid. If $C$ is a category, then a comonad on $C$ is the same as a comonoid in the endofunctor category $[C, C]$, seen as a strict monoidal category with endofunctor composition as monoidal product. Thus, given a comonad on $C$, we get a unique strict monoidal functor (cont.) 

Comment: $\Delta^{op} \to [C, C]$ which classifies that comonad. So the question is: what sort of simplicial objects in $[C, C]$ are monoidal functors? Abstracting away from this, we might as well ask: if $D$ is a strict monoidal category, what sort of functors $\Delta \to D$ correspond to those induced from monoids? And I don't know how to answer that without referring to the chosen monoidal structure on $D$. You get different answers depending on which monoidal structure you choose. I don't think the question is nonsense, but it requires the ability to sniff out the *intended* monoidal structure. 

Comment: Thanks very much for the info.  So, @Sean, I'm not sure if it's always acyclic, and the bar construction I'm familiar with I guess is very specific to either groups or $R$-modules, though I can see how it could generalized. At the moment I'm reading in Charles Weibel's book, and he refers to such simplicial objects as "aspherical" (which I think is essentially acyclic) if the object that we build the construction over is "$\bot$-projective".  So I'm not entirely sure how it all works out but I think that this sort of thing is not always acyclic, necessarily.  



Comment: @Tom, you're right and perhaps the question was in fact imprecise since indeed an object is required to do anything at all.  So I'm not sure, do we just require the category to have objects? Is that sufficient?  

The basic construction I'm referring to is as follows: We have a cotriple $(\bot,\epsilon, \delta)$, $\bot:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$, $\epsilon:\bot\Rightarrow 1$, $\delta:\bot\Rightarrow\bot\bot$ which satisfy the necessary diagrams (associativity and unitality).  Now, assume we have an object $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$.  So we can construct a simplicial object where the $n$th level...

Comment: ...(I think above I mean co-unitality)... the $n$th level is $\bot^{n+1}A$ and the face operators at that level are given by the $n+1$ places I can delete a $\bot$ using $\epsilon$ and the degeneracy operators are given by the $n+1$ places we can insert a $\bot$ using $\delta$ (this perhaps non-standard as I refer to the face operators going down from level $n+1$ and the degeneracy operators going up from that same level, not TO that level).  Anyway, it is tedious and unpleasant to check that these meet all the necessary conditions but they do.  So you're right Tom, what the heck do I mean...

Comment: ...when referring to a "simplicial object" associated to a comonad, because there is not one.  Perhaps I mean some kind of simplicial functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to \mathrm{SSet}(\mathcal{C})$.  But then again, I haven't run into a lot of "simplicial functors," so perhaps this is not an interesting question...